# "It only matters the story they tell when you're gone"

Tags: grammaticality

Lionsgate just released a [poster](http://www.impawards.com/2019/kid.html) and a [trailer](https://twitter.com/MovieTheKid/status/1098628419573567489) for their upcoming western movie *The Kid*, with the tagline "It only matters the story they tell when you're gone".

As far as I can think of, the only occasions in which the verb *matter* takes an object are when it's an interrogative, as in "It doesn't matter what the intent is."

Is "It only matters the story they tell when you're gone" grammatical? If so, how is it parsed? And what does it mean? If not, what is the effect they are supposedly trying to achieve with the tagline?

Comment: The only time _matter_ can take an object (and I’m not even sure that’s a true object – it’s perhaps more adverbial in nature) is when it’s a quantifier: “It doesn’t matter _one iota_ what the intent is”. The last bit, “what the intent is” is not an object, but an extrapositioned subject, replaced in the subject position by the dummy pronoun _it_. That’s also the case in your example here: “the story they tell when you’re gone” is extrapositioned. I agree it’s ungrammatical in that case, though.

Comment: @Janus Yeah, I thought about that. Would "the only occasions in which the verb *matter* can be followed by a noun phrase" be better?

Comment: "All that really matters is the story they tell when you're gone" -- Tag lines **do not** need to be grammatical and more often than not, they are not.

Comment: @Kris Then why do you think they chose this sentence? Is it something people might have typically said in the Old West, for example?

Comment: Maybe. It may even have to do with the theme of the movie itself, as you seem to imply. Else it could be a pun on something more familiar.